# How to link to images in my images folder on Github?

Tags: css, github, github-pages

[image]

[image]

I have tried this ^HTML as well as ../images/IMG_6341.jpg but none of the images are displaying on my github pages. CSS, Javascript and HTML are loading perfectly, just not the linked images. It worked when they were not in the images folder and the src was a simple 'IMG-6341.jpg'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You are missing `url()` on `background` property value.
- Should be `background: url(/images/IMG_6341.jpg);`

Snippet:

```css
body {
  background: url(https://placehold.it/500x500) no-repeat center center;
}
```